# php main menu - add active class to parent if children is being viewed

Tags: php

I've read many answers (many seem to be Wordpress-specific though) but don't understand how to apply them to this situation.

I'm setting an active class on nav items like this:

```
<li class="<?= ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/about' ? 'active' : ''); ?>">
```

---

#### Question:

Is there a way to get php to exclude everything after `/about` so the active class gets applied to any child with a parent of  `/about/`?

Something like this?

```
'/about/*'
```

Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<li class="<?= (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/about') === 0 ? 'active' : ''); ?>">
```

Comment: Cheers - just what I was looking for.